# filtering geoJSON data using JMESPath not working

Tags: json, filter, geojson, jmespath

I am trying to filter some data from the geoJSON data structure shown as below:

```
 "features": [
 {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/7071544593",
        "addr:city": "Joensuu",
        "addr:housenumber": "12",
        "addr:postcode": "80100",
        "addr:street": "Siltakatu",
        "addr:unit": "C 33",
        "alt_name": "Crasman Oy Joensuu",
        "alt_name_1": "Crasman Oy",
        "name": "Crasman Joensuu",
        "short_name": "Crasman",
        "website": "https://www.crasman.fi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          29.7621398,
          62.6015236
        ]
      },
      "id": "node/7071544593"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/7117872562",
        "amenity": "car_rental",
        "operator": "avis"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          29.7630643,
          62.6036656
        ]
      },
      "id": "node/7117872562"
    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is iterate through this array of features, look into the properties object to check if it contains website, if Yes, then I can print its coordinates from geometry object.
This is what I tried:

```
Features[*].properties[?contains(@,'website')=='true'].geometry.coordinates
```

It gives me null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
features[?contains(keys(properties),'website')].geometry.coordinates
```

E.g.:

```
$ jp "features[?contains(keys(properties),'website')].geometry.coordinates" <input.json
[
  [
    29.7621398,
    62.6015236
  ]
]
```

With regard to why your example didn't work:

- Identifiers are case-sensitive, so you need `features`, not `Features`.
- `properties` is an object, not an array, so you can't apply a filter expression to it.
- Even if you could, it's not `properties` that you want to filter. You are trying to filter whole *`features`*.
- `contains` tests if an array contains an item (or if a string contains a substring), not whether an object has a key. You can use `keys()` to get the keys of an object in an array.
- You don't need to compare the result of `contains()` to `true`, it's already a boolean.
- Even if you were trying to compare to `true`, you'd need to use backticks: `` `true` ``, not quotes `'true'`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.